# Project Euler #4 in C#

Tags: c#

I'm attempting to do Project Euler problem #4 in C#. The problem I'm having is that when the code runs a console window briefly appears and then goes away. I don't know what the problem could be as I'm relatively new to programming.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            for (int i = 1000; i > 100; i--)
                for (int j = 1000; j > 100; j--)
                    PalCheck(i * j);
        }

        static void PalCheck(int original)
        {
            var reversed = new string(Convert.ToString(original).ToCharArray().Reverse().ToArray());

            if (Convert.ToString(original) == reversed)
                Console.WriteLine(original);

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What would you like to happen? What is the smallest program in which you can make the problem occur / disappear? What if you wait for user input before the end of the program? ("press any key to continue...")?

Comment: I would like it to write the largest palindrome of two three digit numbers. (Thus starting at 1000X1000 and counting down) The line Console.ReadKey(); should wait for user input.

Comment: Have you tried stepping through with the debugger with multiple breakpoints to know what was going on?

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault No, as I honestly don't know how too. Guess have I have something to read up on.

Comment: "two three digit numbers". Did you mean for the upper limit of `j` to be `10000` instead of `1000`? Not sure it matters...

Comment: @GrantWinney I just copied it into a brand new project and running it gives the same error. No there is no other code.

Comment: @Floris Just noticed that, I changed it in my code though and got the same result.

Comment: It does seem that as written you wait for input on every palindrome check, not just when you have a match. But that should make the program halt more, not less. What happens if you add a `WriteLine` statement at the start of every call to `PalCheck()`? What is the first value of `original`? Perhaps your compiler hits an overflow condition (on some machines an `int` is < 1M).

Answer (score 1):

The code seems to be stuck at the line
Console.ReadKey() as at this line of code, the program is waiting for some input key.
Since you have not used any message before ReadKey(), you don't realize that the program is waiting for some input and not stuck.

Move Console.ReadKey() after PalCheck(i * j) and you should see the output on the console screen.

Comment: Moving Console.ReadKey() after Palcheck(i*j) returns a list of all the palindromes that are products of three digit numbers. It solves the problem of the console breifly appearing but doesn't give me the answer.

Comment: If you want to stop after the first valid check you need to make sure that you do a `ReadKey` only after the `if` statement is satisfied - use `{}`...

Comment: I added brackets to the if statement and put the Console.GetKey() line inside the brackets. Now it returns a palindrome every time I hit a key. I see the correct answer after pressing a key a few times, but it isn't the first result.

Comment: Also the list seems to go on forever, holding down a key just makes it run.